# Strange Fills in paths on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, stroke, fill

I don't understand where are these fills coming from. I only have strokes selected on this shape yet I get these little fills. This is very annoying. Anyone know what are these or how to prevent the illustrator from behaving this way?

[image: Strange fills]

Comment: Could be a number of reasons for this. Please provide an outline view screenshot via CTRL+Y.

Comment: You might also want to send us a screenshot of your layers. If this is indeed a path with stroke and no fill, then this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Probably just a glitch in the gpu preview turn it off and look what the software rasterizer does.

Comment: Thank you commenters. Indeed it was a GPU glitch. When I turn off Preferences > Performence > GPU Performence the weird fillings go away. Is it a local issue like drivers or GPU settings or perhaps IE incompatibility? I guess I just have to live with them.